# How can I bootstrap a Deming regression estimates in R?

Tags: r, regression, statistics-bootstrap

i am working on a consulting problem that involves error-in-variables (Deming) regression to compare two measurement techniques.  The details are given in a question I asked on CV. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38023/error-in-variables-regression-is-it-valid-to-pool-data-from-three-sites) is the link.  Bill Huber pointed me to the `mcr` package on `cran` that will solve the Deming regression problem. I was asked to make a bootstrap correction because some of the data points could be correlated.

Can any expert in `R` on this site show me how I could imbed the Deming regression in a bootstrap procedure?

Comment: @smilig.  Thanks for editing my question and adding the name of the mrc package.

Comment: No problem @Michael. As a side note, people are usually more willing and interested to answer questions that provide some example data. Here's a reference point, if you haven't seen it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1088647

Comment: This is a link to a posting to Rhelp by Terry Thereau. It has the code for what he was calling generalized Deming regression based on an article by Ripley.http://markmail.org/message/4mo62jqfyudrchzi?q=list:org%2Er-project%2Er-help+deming+therneau . Despite his statement that the code would not remain attached ... it was.